# Is possible to create a class with generic in this way?

Tags: java, generics

I'd like to know if this creation is possible:

```
Class<String> stringClass = String.class;
MyGenericClass<stringClass> myGenericClass;
```

I tried in my IDE, but I get a compilation error.

Comment: If you got a compilation error, then that _creation_ is not possible.

Comment: The answer is in the question, it is not possible

Comment: But maybe you can use another trick

Comment: Do you mind if I ask your use-case for this?  I'm pretty curious.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it answers itself.

Comment: @JasonMArcher in the topic I put in this way, but I was not saying that I want to create the Generic objects exactly as I put in my comment. But, instead, using variables. There are methods in whatEverObject.class.someMethod() which maybe could be used. Then, once I saw the comments I can say that it is not possible.

Comment: @JeffGohlke I want to read from a File what is the Type of the polymorphic object I want to create.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Java language specification says this about [type arguments](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.5.1)

> **Type arguments may be either reference types or wildcards**. Wildcards
>   are useful in situations where only partial knowledge about the type
>   parameter is required.

An object, `stringClass` in this example, is not a reference type nor a wildcard.

A type argument, the part you put between `<>` in a parameterized type variable declaration, constructor or method invocation expression, etc., can **only** be a reference type or a wildcard. For example,

```
MyGenericClass<String> variable;
// or
MyGenericClass<?> variable;
```

Note that primitive types also cannot be used as type arguments.

Answer (score 1):

No it is not possible, the type declaration must be a compile time constant and cannot be a variable.